# setting xulrunner browser preferences

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I am using a xulrunner-1.9.2.12.en-US.win32 for an app I am creating.
I want the user to be able to change the colours of the app using something similar to the "tools, options, content, colors" menu in firefox.

I am using a prefwindow to set browser.display.background_color using a colour picker.
If I look at chrome://global/content/config.xul I see that the value for this property has been correctly changed, however, I see no corresponding change in the web page look and feel. If I view this web page in firefox and make the same changes through tools, options etc, the page changes as expected.

I changed my prefs.js file to the following as a test, with no result:
pref("browser.display.foreground_color", "#000000");

pref("browser.display.background_color", "#FF0000");

pref("browser.display.use_document_colors", false);

pref("browser.display.use_system_colors", false);

pref("browser.preferences.instantApply", false);

pref("browser.preferences.animateFadeIn", false);

I will also add my xul file - appologies for the length of the post:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<prefwindow xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<prefpane id="colorOptions" label="Colours">
<preferences>
<preference id="browser.display.foreground_color" name="browser.display.foreground_color" type="string"/>
<preference id="browser.display.background_color" name="browser.display.background_color" type="string"/>
</preferences>
<groupbox flex="1">
<caption label="Colour preferences"/>
<label value="Background colour" control="bgColour"/>
<colorpicker type="button" id="bgColour"preference="browser.display.background_color"/>
<label value="Foreground colour" control="fgColour"/>
<colorpicker type="button" id="fgColour" preference="browser.display.foreground_color"/>
<label value="Random colour" control="col"/>
<colorpicker type="button" id="col"/>
</groupbox>
</prefpane>
</prefwindow>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced,
Ant

Answer (score 2):

In my application using xulrunner 1.9.0.3082 I had to change the file

> defaults/prefs/xulrunner.js

With the following additional line all texts are shown in a beautiful blue:

```
pref("browser.display.foreground_color", "#00A4FA");
```

Any changes to the file pref.js were not successful!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug in xulrunner.
If I set xulrunner to open http://www.google.com and open the about:config panel and set
browser.display.background_color and
browser.display.use_document_colors
I see no change in the web page.

Doing the same thing with Firefox yeilds the expected results.
I have entered a bug report and will post any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Since firefox is using Xulrunner too, I guess the bug would be present in Firefox too if it were one. Are you using the same version of firfox and xulrunner?

According to [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.display.background_color) you need to set browser.display.use_system_colors to false so that the background color have an effect. Maybe that's why it did not change in xulrunner.

Considering your code I don't see why it does not work but there is no space between "bgcolour" and "preference" maybe that could be an error.

Comment: Hi, yea, my version of firefox was the same as xulrunner. I also can see from the about config that the foreground, background, use_system_colors and use_default_colors are expected, but with no resulting change on the web page. I've had to create a work around in my project. I am assuming the issue is either permissions based (a fault in my code) or a bug, I'll post any change in the bug status that enlightens.