# Instead of displaying pdf files in Red Hat Linux, the SWT browser opens a save prompt. Is there any way to handle this?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, rhel, xulrunner

My application is based on eclipse 4.4.2 and has a preview pdf functionality which opens pdf files in a SWT browser. The pdf files open just fine in Windows in the SWT browser but in linux the save prompt opens instead which defeats the whole purpose of that particular functionality. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Show us an [mcve].

Comment: Is this question related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54803519/6505250) (do you use XULRunner on Linux)?

Comment: @howlger - yes this is related to that.

Comment: i cannot use pdf.js as it needs a server in order to work.

Comment: @KnightoftheVale To my knowledge PDF.js can be used offline (in Firefox it is included as PDF viewer).

Comment: as for the solutions present on the internet, pdf.js doesn't look like a viable option - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785198/use-pdf-js-to-statically-convert-a-pdf-to-html   It would at least need to be served from localhost.